# c# a simple debugging question

Tags: c#, .net

```
for (i........)
{
//code
if (specimen == "AA161794") 
   Application.Run();
//more code
}
```

the if statement is there for debugging purposes. i need to examine some of the variables when specimen is that value. instead of `application.run()` i just need a generic piece of code to put in there so that it can stop there. it can be something like

> messagebox.show("Blah");

what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Cant you just set a break point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to make a Conditional Breakpoint.
Right-click the breakpoint and click `Condition...`.

Alternatively, write `"".ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following: `Debug.Assert(false);`

Answer (score 2):

To use existing constant

```
 # if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("debug mode");
 #  endif
```

If you define your own constant "Legacy"

```
 #if Legacy
            Console.WriteLine("legacy mode");
 # endif
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting a Breakpoint in your IDE (visual studio or monodevelop)

here is a nice article of how to setup Conditional breakpoints

http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/02/14/visual-studio-2008-debugging-tricks-ndash-advanced-breakpoints.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308469

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use `Debugger.Break` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx